# Remove to the DotPlot the genes with the same expression between the identity

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, dot-plot

I want to remove from the dot plot the genes that have the same expression in the different identities (clusters).

I do my DotPlot with this command:
`DotPlot(S_obj, features=gene_int) + RotatedAxis()`

I have big list of gene and I want to select only genes with big difference of expression between the clusters. Is there any way to make this selection on the Dotplot?